# Cut off text height at a given value

Tags: boxes, height

Is it possible to have a text box which cuts of text running out of its height?
Considering the following minimal working example, I would like to have the text in the first `parbox` to be cut of as soon as it flows out of the 20mm height:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}                % language package
\setmainlanguage{english}               % select language for polyglossia
\begin{document}
  \parbox[c][20mm][t]{20mm}{\strut\hspace{0pt}Some Text in the first column which is higher, than 20mm in total \strut}\par
  \parbox[t]{50mm}{\strut\hspace{0pt}Some other Text, which should be here \strut}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to have a behavior similar to HTML resp. CSS

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 20mm; height: 20mm;"></div>
```

Comment: i can think of two possible approaches: (1) make the subject box into a graphic, at which point functions like `clip` can be applied, or (2) overprint it with a white band (again using a graphics approach).  i don't know of any non-graphical approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [trimclip packages](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/adjustbox/trimclip.pdf) `\clipbox` macro with all values set to `0pt` seams to do the trick as exacted:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}                % language package
\usepackage{trimclip}                   % provides the \clipbox macro
\setmainlanguage{english}               % select language for polyglossia
\begin{document}
  \clipbox{0pt 0pt 0pt 0pt}{\parbox[c][20mm][t]{20mm}{\strut\hspace{0pt}Some Text in the first column which is higher, than 20mm in total \strut}}\par
  \parbox[t]{50mm}{\strut\hspace{0pt}Some other Text, which should be here \strut}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `trimclip` package can be used within `tikz` environment. If you are interested in clipping within a `pspicture` using `pstricks` you have to use the `\clipbox` makro provided by `pstricks` which has a slightly different syntax as can be see in chapter 28 of the [`pstricks` User's guide](http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pstricks-doc.pdf).

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seam to work within a `pspicture` environment … :-(

Comment: Ok, this package doesn't work in pstricks. pstricks rather holds its own implementation of `\clipbox` as can be see in chapter 28 of the pstricks User's guide http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pstricks-doc.pdf.