# Set tabular column width but prevent multiple lines

Tags: tables

With the following example the column width is set, and that is exactly what I want. However, in this unusual case I want to prevent the multiple lines and neglect the following text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| p{0.20\linewidth} | p{0.80\linewidth} |}
    \hline
    \textbf{name} & \textbf{story} \\
    \hline
    Eric & kjnf sdf df e f efef efef wefef efeaf seaf efeaf eafaef \\ \hline
    Frits & jfenr efn efue eufh ehuee eahf aehfueah wer fehfuen  dnwja wndwndud wduw dwuhaw ahuada huawd haduwa huwad a hawu hsna anmedn \\ \hline
    Bas & kjnf sdf df e f efef efef wefef efeaf seaf efeaf eafaef \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: desired result]

Comment: Using `clipbox`? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230092/cut-off-text-hight-than-a-given-value